# SessionScoped Bean @PostConstruct called twice

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, managed-bean, postconstruct

I have a SessionScoped bean to manage user authentication. The main page displays some additional text if the user is authenticated

```
 <h:outputText value="welcome " rendered="#{loginBean.isLoggedIn}" />
```

When the page loads I can see that the *@PostConstruct* is called (as expected) just after the *START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6*

When the user clicks login I load a form and I can see that the login method is called when the user submits a login (also authentication works). Thereafter the user is redirected back to the original page. Just after *START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6* the *@PostConstruct* of the loginBean is once again called !

```
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: Constructor called 1 times !
INFO: In constructor FROM is greeting.xhtml
INFO: Get is logged in called and value is false
INFO: Get is logged in called and value is false
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: Getting sendto=<greeting.xhtml>
INFO: END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: START PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: END PHASE UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: START PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: Session is not null
INFO: login method of the login bean has been called
INFO: login success
INFO: END PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
INFO: Constructor called 2 times !
```

I have checked imports 
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

I have read a number of answers about this issue, however, still uncertain as to how to solve this. Any ideas ?

Here is the main page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./newTemplate.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="title">
                Greeting
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="top">
                   <div class="menu">
                    <ul id="list-nav">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/MaxThePuppyCompany-    war/faces/greeting.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <p:lightBox name="myLightbox" id="myLightbox">  
                                <h:outputLink value="#">  
                                    <h:outputText value="Video Content"/>  
                                    </h:outputLink>  

                                <f:facet name="inline">  
                                    <p:media value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=18079550"  width="400" height="225" player="flash"/>  
                                </f:facet>  
                            </p:lightBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <p:lightBox widgetVar="myPopup" id="mPopup">
                               <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="myPopup.show();">  
                                    <h:outputText value="Products"/>  
                                </h:outputLink>                          
                            <f:facet name="inline">
                                <ui:include src="/popups/products.xhtml"  />
                             </f:facet>                                                                     
                            </p:lightBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <p:lightBox widgetVar="myLoginPopup" >
                               <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="loadLogin();">  
                                    <h:outputText value="Login"/>  
                                </h:outputLink>           
                               <f:facet name="inline">
                                <div id="mLoginPopup"></div>
                               </f:facet>
                            </p:lightBox>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.isLoggedIn}"/>
                         </li>

                    </ul>

                 </div>

            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="left">

            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="right">
                right
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                content
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="bottom">
                bottom
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the SessionScoped Bean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.Principal;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
    private static int calls;

    //@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.from}")
    private String sendto;
    //private String from;

    private  int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n) {
        int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
        while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1) {
            pos = str.indexOf(c, pos+1);
        }
        return pos;
    }


    public LoginBean(){
              calls++;
        System.out.println("Constructor called " + calls + " times !");
        //this.sendto =     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("from");
                        ExternalContext ec =     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                        String tmp =  (String)     ec.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
                        if(tmp != null) {
                            int index= this.nthOccurrence(tmp, '/', 1);
                            this.sendto = tmp.substring(index);
                        } else {
                            this.sendto = "greeting.xhtml";
                        }
      System.out.println("In constructor FROM is " + this.sendto);
                        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);


                        if(session != null){
                               System.out.println("In Constructor Session is " +     session.toString());
                            //session.invalidate();
                        }      
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if the user has been logged in
     * @return
     */
    public boolean getIsLoggedIn() {
                      System.out.println("Get is logged in called and value is " +     this.isLoggedIn);
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    /*
    public String getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    public void setFrom (String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    */
    public String getSendto() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //
        //this.sendto = "/admin/aminConsole.xhtml";
        System.out.println("Getting sendto=<" + this.sendto + ">");
        return this.sendto;
    }

    public void setSendto(String sendto) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        //this.sendto = sendto;
    }

    public String register() {
        return "Register";
    }

    public String login(){
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the managed bean to us? And the rest of the relevant part of your view.

Comment: agreed, I can't tell heads or tails of your description.

Comment: Sorry for that ! As I was posting the code I found the problem. The login method was calling session.invalidate() to solve a previous isue with a user logging in twice ...